# Modeling Optional Foreign Key from Composite Primary Key field (Oracle Data Modeler)

Tags: database-design

I am trying to add an optional foreign key in Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler v4.1.0.873(Build 873), as per diagram below:

[image]

The issue is that I can only make such a relationship if it is mandatory (note solid black line - I need it to be dotted).  The 'Mandatory' checkbox cannot be unchecked, or where it can be, I get:

> MKT_DATA_BONDS__FK: FK cannot be optional because some columns are
>   part of the PK

How do I show this relationship in the model?  (We don't want the BONDS table to contain all bonds).  I tried adding an index (on BOND_ID) but wasn't able to reference that either.

Comment: What do you mean by "We don't want the BONDS table to contain all bonds)." ?  What should be stored in "BONDS" then ?

Comment: Just those bonds that the company holds, or has an interest in.  The point is that there may be records in the MKT_DATA_BONDS table that don't have a corresponding record in the BONDS table.  There is probably a good argument to exclude those records from MKT_DATA_BONDS (given the company is not interested in them) but I'm still interested to know if the constraint can be made optional..

Comment: Then you need to redesign table structure. If `MKT_DATA_BONDS` can have records which are not in `BONDS` then it implies `BONDS` is details table and needs FK to `MKT_DATA_BONDS` . However, FK in Oracle must refer to unique constraint in the main table (not to part of constraint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the foreign key in the wrong table. Your defining entity is in the MKT_DATA_BONDS table. The refering entity is in the BONDS table. Each BOND must be defined in MKT_DATA_BONDS. The "optional" part is carried out by the fact that not all market bonds need be represented as a company bond.

To put it in OO language, market bond is the super or parent class. A company bond is one (of possibly several) sub or derived classes. Subclasses know about super classes, but the super class doesn't know about (or refer to) any subclass.

Comment: I think the main point here is that a 'defining entity' is mandatory in the oracle data model, and that any FKs must reference a unique constraint in that regard (as raised by @a1ex07).  For our purposes (given that bonds are not unique in our MKT_DATA_BONDS table) we may go with a separate bonds table (with all bonds), or we may just override those constraints in the physical implementation.  Thanks for the advice!